# TYPO3 Form Framework Unique Selectable Identifier

Tags: javascript, typo3, unique, typo3-10.x, formframework

I have a question to form framework. For some reasons it would be great to let editors add forms to a website.
My problem now is that I want to standardise for example mails.
So my idea was/is to add a field to all form elements with a list of identifier to use them for mail templates.

For now I have a required field but I need a check for unique value of the whole form.. is that possible?
I have a custom InspectorComponent.js for my field so I would check for unique if I change the select:

```
 selectElement.on('change', function() {
        getCurrentlySelectedFormElement().set(propertyPath, $('option:selected', $(this)).data('value'));
        _validateCollectionElement(propertyPath, editorHtml);
      });
```

Does anybody know how I can get all formelements from the current form and get the field values?
Or is it possible to add a custom propertyValidator for unique, is that possible?
Actually I set the validator to "NotEmpty" because its required to set the select.
If this is possible, how can I look for unique value for all form elements?

Maybe there are other solutions?

TYPO3 10.4.37